# Create several columns from a complex column in R

Tags: r, split, columnsorting

Imagine dataset:

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(~City,   ~Population,
"United Kingdom > Leeds",   1500000,
"Spain > Las Palmas de Gran Canaria",   200000,
"Canada > Nanaimo, BC", 150000,
"Canada > Montreal",    250000,
"United States > Minneapolis, MN",  700000,
"United States > Milwaukee, WI",    NA,
"United States > Milwaukee",    400000)
```

The same dataset for visual representation:

[image]

I would like to:

1. Split column City into three columns: City, Country, State (if available, NA otherwise)
2. Check that Milwaukee has data in state and population (the NA for Milwaukee should have a value of 400000 and then split [City-State-Country] :).

Could you, please, suggest the easiest method to do so :)

Comment: look at `dplyr::separate()` for the first part

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution with `extract` to do the extraction of `Country`, `City`, and `State` in a single go with `State` extracted by an optional capture group (the remainder of the task is done as by @Allen's code):

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  extract(City,
          into = c("Country", "City", "State"),
          regex = "([^>]+) > ([^,]+),? ?([A-Z]+)?"
        ) %>%
  # as by @Allen Cameron:
  group_by(Country, City) %>%
  summarize(State = ifelse(all(is.na(State)), NA, State[!is.na(State)]), 
            Population = Population[!is.na(Population)])
```

Comment: Dear Chris! Thanks for the solution, however, I have an issue with replicability: > df1 %>%
+   extract(City,
+           into = c("Country", "City", "State"),
+           regex = "([^>]+) > ([^,]+),? ?([A-Z]+)?"
+         ) %>%
+ group_by(Country, City) %>%
+   summarize(State = ifelse(all(is.na(State)), NA, State[!is.na(State)]), 
+             Population = Population[!is.na(Population)])
Error in `[.tbl_df`(., City, into = c("Country", "City", "State"), regex = "([^>]+) > ([^,]+),? ?([A-Z]+)?") : 
  object 'City' not found
(All + are from R output, the input was correct)

Comment: df1 %>%
  tidyr::extract(City,
          into = c("Country", "City", "State"),
          regex = "([^>]+) > ([^,]+),? ?([A-Z]+)?"
        ) %>%
  # as by @Allen Cameron:
  dplyr::group_by(Country, City) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(State = ifelse(all(is.na(State)), NA, State[!is.na(State)]), 
            Population = Population[!is.na(Population)])
# It helped - it seems library function overlapping issue :) Thanks for the suggested solution :)

Comment: yes, the function name `extract` is used elsewhere too!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `separate` twice to get the country and state, then `group_by` Country and City to summarize away the NA values where appropriate:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  separate(City, sep = " > ", into = c("Country", "City")) %>%
  separate(City, sep = ', ', into = c('City', 'State')) %>%
  group_by(Country, City) %>%
  summarize(State = ifelse(all(is.na(State)), NA, State[!is.na(State)]), 
            Population = Population[!is.na(Population)])
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   Country [4]
#>   Country        City                       State Population
#>   <chr>          <chr>                      <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 Canada         Montreal                   <NA>      250000
#> 2 Canada         Nanaimo                    BC        150000
#> 3 Spain          Las Palmas de Gran Canaria <NA>      200000
#> 4 United Kingdom Leeds                      <NA>     1500000
#> 5 United States  Milwaukee                  WI        400000
#> 6 United States  Minneapolis                MN        700000
```

Comment: Dear Allan! Thanks. However, I have a replicability issue: > df1 %>%
+   separate(City, sep = " > ", into = c("Country", "City")) %>%
+   separate(City, sep = ', ', into = c('City', 'State')) %>%
+   group_by(Country, City) %>%
+   summarize(State = ifelse(all(is.na(State)), NA, State[!is.na(State)]), 
+             Population = Population[!is.na(Population)])
Error: (converted from warning) Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 4 rows [1, 2, 4, 7]. #(All + are from R, the input was correct)

Comment: df1 %>%
  tidyr::separate(City, sep = " > ", into = c("Country", "City")) %>%
  tidyr::separate(City, sep = ', ', into = c('City', 'State')) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(Country, City) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(State = ifelse(all(is.na(State)), NA, State[!is.na(State)]), 
            Population = Population[!is.na(Population)])
Error: (converted from warning) Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 4 rows [1, 2, 4, 7].